# Android fingerprint scanner is not recognised

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fingerprint-api

I have a device which has a fingerprint sensor on a home button. Other applications seems to recognise and handle it properly however the application I am building is failing at couple of steps:

I am using android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompat

```
// at this point isHardwareDetected returns false
val fingerprintManager = FingerprintManagerCompat.from(context)
if (!fingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected) {
    return false
}
```

If I skip hardware detection step it still fails at

```
// hasEnrolledFingerprints returns false even tough there 
// are couple of fingerprints registered
if (!fingerprintManager.hasEnrolledFingerprints()) {
    return false
}
```

The device is UMI Plus E Android 6.0.1

What can be wrong with it?

Additionally here's my manifest regarding fingerprint:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.fingerprint" android:required="false" />
```

**Edit**

I solved this issue by using reprint library: https://github.com/ajalt/reprint

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of fingerprint authentication in Github, please check and see the result:

[Fingerprint Authentication](https://github.com/hamedrezaee/FingerprintAuthentication)

you can also use this helper method for further usages:

```
public static boolean isFingerprintDefined(@NonNull Context context) {
    return FingerprintManagerCompat.from(context).isHardwareDetected() && FingerprintManagerCompat.from(context).hasEnrolledFingerprints();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work and the library that the application that you provided uses says that device doesn't support fingerprint

Comment: I know some fingerprint sensors dose not support officially, for instance old Samsung cell phones do it by own API libraries. probably this phone did that so.

Answer (score 0):

Seems more like a hardware issue,

- Try removing all fingerprints and adding new ones, if you got error while adding new fingerprints like `Hardware not ready` etc, it means something wrong with the hardware sensor.
- you can also try dialing *#808# on your device and go to finger print test . And do a finger print auto test, it will give you brief diagnostic report for your hardware sensor.

Comment: I tried, also I tested on similar device Samsung Galaxy S5 Android 6.0.1 version, which has the same issue. I tested sensor seems to work fine, and other apps seems to be working alright

Answer (score 0):

I remember long time ago, I faced the same problem. It was the issue with `FingerprintManagerCompat` class from support library. Try using the `FingerprintManager` class from platform or update to the latest version of support library.